# Cannot leave swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've been tinkering with new Docker swarm mode. I can't fully recall the steps that I did, but now I'm stuck in situation where my docker engine is as a worker in a non-existing swarm:

```
$ docker info
...
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 1vndsuqa0r3paswufs7eq4po3
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 192.168.65.2
...

$ docker swarm leave
Error response from daemon: context deadline exceeded

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:04:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: true

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:04:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

How could I get out the swarm mode?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you like to downvote so that I can improve my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this by resetting docker back to factory defaults from `Docker menu > Preferences > Uninstall / Reset > Reset to factory defaults` (I'm using Docker for Mac beta). Note that this operation also swipes all docker images, volumes, networks, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this was a bug in `1.12.0` that has been resolved since (I believe the patch should be included in `1.12.3`). Here is the [Related Issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25432).

But if the problem persists with the new version somehow, there are a few additional options:

```
# Force quit the cluster

docker swarm leave --force
```

or

```
# Force a new cluster and leave properly

docker swarm init --force-new-cluster
docker swarm leave
```